# Trying to read a csv file with embedded quotes using csvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Below is an small snippet of a CSV I have to read and parse. I don't know how it was created, supposedly it is a valid CSV file.
Using CSVHelper it is executing the BadDataExceptionHandler setup in the Configuration

```
field1,field2,field3,field4
6/22/2020,7"X8.5"SIGNTYPE2.L,*299334,7"X8.5"SIGNTYPE2.L
7/30/2020,OMTOTE,GS350006,OMTOTE
```

If I submit original file to an online CSV linter, it complains that the CSV contents has a bad structure.

If I open this file up in Excel, it doesn't give me an exception and the spreadsheet looks like the record above. But if i save the file as a *.csv, the new file has the double quotes escaped like so.

```
  6/22/2020,"7""X8.5""SIGNTYPE2.L",*299334,"7""X8.5""SIGNTYPE2.L"
```

I tried to set Configuration.IgnoreQuotes = true, but that throws a "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'"  exception.

Is there a way to process the file successfully using csvHelper?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Make sure the [mcve] **includes the entire string you are trying to parse in code** so we can repro the issue quickly.

Comment: Given the file isn't a valid CSV, have you considered using Excel to parse it instead?

Comment: @mjwills I will update with runnable code snippet. my example csv is just a subset of the fields. having Excel do the parsing is not an option for me. These CSV files will potentially be wide records (many fields) and millions of rows. The end-product will need to be fruggle with memory. Excel or closedXML will read in the entire file. I need something that i can enumerate over so as to not use up much memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have saved and opened the data with Microsoft Excel and it is working perfectly
So Try this
Instal LumenWorksCsvReader

```
Install-Package LumenWorksCsvReader -Version 4.0.0
```

and read you file as

```
           using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(csvFile), true))
            {
                csv.DefaultParseErrorAction = ParseErrorAction.RaiseEvent;
                int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
                string[] lines = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

                while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                {
                    List<string> rowData= new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        rowData.Add(csv[i]);
                    }
                }
             }
```

Comment: I just pasted the `field1,field2,field3,field4
6/22/2020,7"X8.5"SIGNTYPE2.L,*299334,7"X8.5"SIGNTYPE2.L
7/30/2020,OMTOTE,GS350006,OMTOTE` in notepad++ , saved the file as .csv and opened it with Excel